# adding the -i flag causes sed to throw an error

Tags: sed

I have a sed command that works just fine if I let the output get sent to stdout

```
sed  s/defaultFedoraColor/grey/ stuff.js
```

however, if I try to change the file in place by add the -i flag

```
sed  -i s/defaultFedoraColor/grey/ stuff.js
```

I get the error message of

```
sed: 1: "stuff.js": unterminated substitute pattern
```

Why would the flag change the legitimacy of my substitution pattern?

Comment: try `sed  -i 's/defaultFedoraColor/grey/' stuff.js`

Comment: Try putting quotes around the command

Comment: quotes around the pattern didn't fix it for me am running os x 10.7.5 but adding making it `sed  -i '' s/defaultFedoraColor/grey/ stuff.js` did fix it

Comment: just for extra fun, adding the '' on ubuntu breaks the command...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-i` flag takes a parameter! This parameter is the backup suffix used for the file being manipulated. (Presumably, a backup of the original file is made with the given suffix.) Therefore, your pattern has become the parameter for -i and sed tries to interpret "stuff.js" as the pattern.

**Edit:** I'm not experiencing this erroneous behaviour at all, though, but that's what a reading of the manpage would suggest to be the issue.

**Another edit:** Perhaps you want to simply add quotes around the pattern as suggested

Comment: that does fix it. The man page says you can put in a "zero length" extension. I read that as leaving it blank, you actually need  to do `sed -i '' s/default/gray stuff.js`